# Terminate tls with ssh port forwarding

Tags: ssh, openssl, socat

There is a TLS wrapped tcp port on a remote machine that I need to forward to a unix domain socket without TLS on my local machine. I know I can do that with ssh and socat but I'm curious if ssh can terminate TLS so I don't need socat.

```
ssh -nNL $local_port:127.0.0.1:$remote_port $host
socat UNIX-LISTEN:$socket,reuseaddr,fork \
      openssl-connect:127.0.0.1:$local_port,cert=cert.pem,cafile=ca.crt,commonname=name
```

Comment: ssh cannot terminate tls.

Comment: If the remote port is open, socat can connect TLS directly to it. However this is not what you asked AND not programming or development.